# "circumstance" or "circumstance of a situation"

Tags: word-usage

> Remember,  the  four  of  you  may  be  proficient,  each  in  your  own  subject,  but  if  you  don’t have the sense to act suitably to the time and **circumstance of a situation,** you may have to go hungry.

This sentence is from " Selected Myanmar Tales"
I am so confused with the usage "circumstance of a situation". I have just learned that "circumstance" means "special situation". Is it needed to add "situation"
after the word "circumstance" ?

Answer (score 1):

> circumstances

(note the plural) means details or conditions about *something*, it does not imply anything *special*.

> of a situation

should be included, especially if being formal, since to only say "time and circumstances", though understandable, may leave things unresolved.